# Difference between criteria and detached criteria in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

What is the difference between criteria and detached criteria? When should we go for criteria and when should we go for detached criteria?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i had same doubt, searched on Google and landed here... instead of answer I saw ur comment first. wished u took this effort to write answer rather than such a comment.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The [detached criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries) allows you to create the query without `Session`. Then you can execute the search in an arbitrary session.

In fact you should think carefully when using a `detached criteria` using another, or a new, session (no cache, and creation of the session).

They are most useful for join conditions, subselects, and to query outside the current session.

Another common use is for code reuse. Many developers declare them as  `static` queries and execute them using the underlying session from different `DAO`.

Comment: Hi Fholl, thanks for your quick response. Are there any advantages with detached criteria over criteria/HQL? any scenario that we should use detached criteria? please reply.

Comment: So basically your suggestion is to use criteria/HQL over detached criteria?

Comment: Yes, use criteria/HQL when possible, over detache

Comment: Hi Fholl, thanks for your reply. if detached criteria is used, when is the queryis attached to session? please reply me.

Comment: It is attached to another session, in hibernate, and that session is created from scratch

Comment: This answer is wrong... DetachedCriterias behave exactly the same as Criterias except you can initially create them without having access to a session.

Comment: I don't get it. What are the drawbacks? Why don't use DetachedCriteria every time?

Answer (score 13):

Using a DetachedCriteria is exactly the same as a Criteria except you can do the initial creation and setup of your query without having access to the session. When it comes time to run your query, you must convert it to an executable query with `getExecutableCriteria(session)`.

This is useful if you are building complicated queries, possibly through a multi-step process, because you don't need access to the Session everywhere. You only need the Session at the final step when you run the query.

Under the hood, DetachedCriteria uses a CriteriaImpl which is the same class you get if you call `session.createCriteria()`.

Comment: Indeed, i always use detached criteria and it requires the session (to do getExecutableCriteria), i was trying to find out who's the best one but i guess this way they're the same

Answer (score 5):

-Detached criteria is very good alternate when the hibernate session is not   present.

-The criteria are online, which means that it uses Session class object. But the detached criteria is offline because it *doesn't need a session*.

-Then the detach criteria allow code reusability.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    System.out.println("By using criteria");

    Criteria cr=session.createCriteria(Student.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("gender", "male"));
    cr.addOrder(Order.asc("stud_id"));
    List<Student> res=((Criteria) cr).list();
    for(int i=0;i<res.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.print( res.get(i).getStud_id()+"\t");
        System.out.println(res.get(i).getName());
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nBy using Detached criteria");
    DetachedCriteria dcr = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Student.class).add(Property.forName("gender").eq("male"));
    dcr.addOrder(Order.desc("stud_id"));
    List<Student> results = dcr.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();
    for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.print( results.get(i).getStud_id()+"\t");
        System.out.println(results.get(i).getName());
    }
```

[Click here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) for implementation notes.

Comment: Add references to your answer

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html - @NSNoob

Answer (score 4):

Just to act as a reminder.
If you are using Spring and choose to use HibernateTemplate, it doesn't provide createCriteria() method.

You will find only DetachedCriteria.

See also:

[HibernateTemplate javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html)