# How to do a Hibernate nested select?

Tags: java, hibernate

Not sure if I worded the question correctly but i'm working with a postgres database

I'm looking for the equivalent of the following sql statement.

Select * from track where id in (Select track_id from track_item where item_time between x and y).

I'm new to hibernate and i've tried doing this using a Hibernate Query and using Criteria and failed both ways.

If there is an awnser using both methods it would be nice to see both examples as I'm trying to learn how to use both.

This is the create table information for the two tables

```
CREATE TABLE track (
id bigint NOT NULL,
track_uuid text,
track_number text,
track_exercise_indicator_id bigint NOT NULL,
track_simulation_indicator_id bigint NOT NULL,
track_status_id bigint,
last_modified timestamp with time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now())
);

CREATE TABLE track_item (
id bigint NOT NULL,
track_item_type_id bigint NOT NULL,
item_time bigint NOT NULL,
frame_number bigint,
image_source text,
last_modified timestamp with time zone DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now()),
track_item_uuid character varying(200) NOT NULL,
track_id bigint NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY track_item
ADD CONSTRAINT track_item_track_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (track_id) REFERENCES track(id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY track_item
ADD CONSTRAINT track_item_track_item_type_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (track_item_type_id) REFERENCES track_item_type(id);
```

The java classes generated from the above table are.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "track", schema = "d2d")
public class Track implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * ID.
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2313376497269789747L;
private long id;
private TrackSimulationIndicator trackSimulationIndicator;
private TrackStatus trackStatus;
private TrackExerciseIndicator trackExerciseIndicator;
private String trackUuid;
private String trackNumber;
private Date lastModified;
private Set<TrackMessageToTrackMapping> trackMessageToTrackMappings = new HashSet<TrackMessageToTrackMapping>(
        0);
private Set<TrackInterval> trackIntervals = new HashSet<TrackInterval>(0);
private Set<AnomalyToTrackMapping> anomalyToTrackMappings = new HashSet<AnomalyToTrackMapping>(
        0);
}




 @Entity
 @Table(name = "track_item", schema = "d2d")
 public class TrackItem implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * ID.
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8469898950069782997L;
private long id;
private TrackItemType trackItemType;
private long itemTime;
private Long frameNumber;
private String imageSource;
private String trackItemUUID;
private Track track;
private Date lastModified;
private Set<TrackPoint> trackPoints = new HashSet<TrackPoint>(0);
private Set<TrackInformation> trackInformations = new HashSet<TrackInformation>(
        0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine came up with this Criteria solution below which works.  The Solution  JB Nizet posted for HQL statement works once he updates the table name and the reference to itemTime.  The HQL query is posted at the bottom of this also.

```
 /**
 * @param p_startTime The date and time in ms
 * @param p_endTime The date and time in ms
 * @param p_session the session
 * @return Returns the latest valid rule for the specified date time
 * @throws IOException
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Track> loadAllTracksByDateRange(final long p_startTime,
        final long p_endTime, final Session p_session) throws IOException {


    // create the criteria
    final Criteria criteria = p_session.createCriteria(TrackItem.class);


    // set projection
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections
            .property("track")));


    // add the restriction
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("itemTime", p_startTime));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.le("itemTime", p_endTime));


    return criteria.list();
}
```

HQL Solution:

```
Select distinct t 
from TrackItem item inner join item.track t 
where item.itemTime between 100L and 200L;
```

Comment: Since JB Nizet isnt updating his awnser to match the .java classes which were posted in the question i'm just going to mark this awnser correct. I dont want to confuse people looking at the solution in relation to the .java calsses. JB Nizet is responsible for the correct HQL solution even though his awnser references tables and variables that dont exist in the .java classes

Answer (score 2):

Your query should use joins to be more efficient, and be more easily translatable in HQL:

```
select distinct t.* from track t
inner join track_item item on t.id = item.track_id
where item.item_time between 100 and 200
```

This SQL query would translate to HQL as:

```
select distinct t from Track t 
inner join t.items item
where item.time between 100 and 200
```

And in Criteria:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Track.class, "t");
c.setResultTransformer(criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
c.createAlias("t.items", "item");
c.add(Restrictions.between("item.time", 100L, 200L);
```

EDIT:

you've mapped the association as a ManyToOne association from TrackItem to Track. The inverse OneToMany association from Track to TrackItem doesn't exist, so the above queries won't work. The following HQL would work though:

```
select distinct t from Item item 
inner join item.track t
where item.time between 100 and 200
```

You can't translate such a query to Criteria though, so you'd better make the association bidirectional: there's no reason for a track to not know about its items.

Comment: I think there is confusion on what is in the track table. Nothing in the track table itself relates to whats in the track_items table other than the tracks id. Its a 1 to many relationship. your line c.createAlias("t.items", "item") doesnt work because the track table contains no column called items. The track table contains the three fields mentioned above.  none the less neither of the queries work. The example using criteria returns an empty list and the HQL query states could not resolve propery:item of: database.model.Track from the query.

Comment: I've noticed that hibernate is very case sensative So alittle more information might help.  The actual table names in the database are track and track_item.  The reverse engineered .java classes which is what I notice most of hibernate references is Track and TrackItem. The important variables in the Track.java is int id and in TrackItem.java long itemTime and Track track.

Comment: You didn't provide the code of your entities, so I had to guess what the name of the classes and properties were. You shouldn't name itemTime a property that is part of a class named TrackItem. It's redundant. Regarding your second comment, I don't understand what you mean by "everything past the = sign returns more than 1 record". If you mean that it returns duplicates, then use `select distinct` instead of `select`.

Comment: Side note your more efficient query is a bad translation of my query as it has errors in it when you try to execute it.  Error missing From-clause entry table "item"

Comment: Each track contains two track items that occur at the same time with different track item types so what i'm looking for is a list of all tracks that occur during a given time constraint which my original query returns. I'll post the create tables for each table to help everyone understand.

Comment: Don't just say "it has errors in it". Tell us which database you're using, and what the exact and complete error message is. Also, you should read a bit of documentation. HQL and Criteria use class names, property/field names, and associations between entities. Never table and column names. If you don't post any code, I can only guess. You should be able to translate my queries to your actual class and field names, given the simplicity and symmetry of the queries.

Comment: You're not trying to execute the HQL query in your database tool, are you? If that's what you are trying, no wonder it doesn't work. HQL is not SQL. HQL is the Hibernate Query Language. It's not understood by databases.

Comment: I tried the SQL statement in my database tool the HQL one in my program code along with the criteria.

Comment: I pasted your SQL creating the tables. It ran after I added the primary key constraints and removed the foreign key to track_item_type. Then I pasted the SQL query I gave you (the very first one in my answer, to be clear), literally, and it ran perfectly fine (on PostgreSQL).

Comment: Your SQL statement works now that you edited it thank you. Your HQL statement is right only your referencing tables that dont exist per the .java classes I posted and time isnt a variable in the .java class either its itemTime. Make the corrections to your HQL statement and I will give you credit for the awnser. Your HQL statement should read Select distinct t from TrackItem item inner join item.track t where item.itemTime between 100L and 200L; I just want to make sure when people read that your awnser is correct that it matches the .java classes I posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do nested selects with the `DetachedCriteria` class:

```
Session s = obtainSession();
Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Track.class);
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TrackItem.class);

dc.setProjection(Property.forName("track"));
dc.add(Restrictions.between("itemTime", x, y));

c.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", dc))
```

Look at questions 
[diff between criteria and detached criteria in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794819/diff-between-criteria-and-detached-criteria-in-hibernate) and 
[when to use detached criteria in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925948/when-to-use-detached-criteria-in-hibernate)
and hibernate documentation [Chapter 15.8](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries) 
for details

Comment: from reading the first question you linked "diff between criteria and detached criteria in hibernate" I got the impression you should avoid detachedCriteria.  Also While I already have a solution I wanted to see if yours worked and it doesnt throw any errors but it returns an empty list.

Comment: Generally speaking you should avoid it, yes, but sometimes it may be an appropriate choice depending on your requirements an/or design. Not quite sure why it returns an empty list, you should have a look at the generated SQL (set hibernate property `show_sql` to `true`) to see what went wrong. (I did not execute the code myself)